# How to loop through a list returned by AsyncStorage

Tags: arrays, react-native, loops, asyncstorage

I have following code returning a list from AsyncStorage like this:

```
[
  {"startTime":"111","endTime":"222"},
  {"startTime":"222","endTime":"333"}`enter code here`
]

const [data, setData] = React.useState();


const fetchValues = async () => {
    try {
      let listvalues = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("@registration"));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error in list getting: ", err);
    }
};
```

I tried typing

```
const listValues = await fetchValues();
```

but this gives an error

> await is only allowed inside async functions),

so instead I tried:

```
React.useEffect(async () => {
    const scopeListValues = await fetchValues();
    setData(scopeListValues);
});
```

But that also gives an error

> useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

What I want to do is to loop though a list like this:

```
return (
  { registrations.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View key={item.key}>
              <Text style={styles.itemStyle}>{item.startTime}</Text>
            </View>
          );
     })
  }
)
```

Comment: First of all, your `fetchValues` function does not return anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can `setData` after fetched from Asyncstorage:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
   AsyncStorage.getItem("@registration").then((_data) => {
      const data = _data && JSON.parse(_data);
      setData(data);
    });
},[])
```

Also, you are mapping through `registrations` but you set value to `data` so change it with `data`:

```
return (
  { data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <View key={item.key}>
              <Text style={styles.itemStyle}>{item.startTime}</Text>
            </View>
          );
     })
  }
)
```

Comment: `React.useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("@registration").then((_data) => {
      const data = _data && JSON.parse(_data);
      setData(data);
      console.log("data: " + data); // prints data: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
    });
  }, []);`

This prints out [object Object],[object Object]... is that intentional? Maybe I should leave out the `&& JSON.parse(_data); part` ?

Comment: This prints out [object Object],[object Object]... is that intentional? Is that how arrays should look like? I thought it were more like this: [{object Object}, {object Object}]  

Anyway, it helped. Thanks!

Comment: Your data is object array so it should print like that but if you want to see data in it you can print it like this `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`.

Answer (score 1):

First fetch values need to return something

```js
const fetchValues = async () => {
    let result = []
    try {
      let listvalues = JSON.parse(
        await AsyncStorage.getItem("@registration")
       );
    result = listvalues

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error in list getting: ", err);
    }
    return result
}
```

Next, useEffect shouldnt be passed an [async function](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect). You can either use then and risk entering callback hell, or you could create and then call a async function in the useEffect:

```js
// using then
React.useEffect(()=>{
   fetchValues.then(res=>{
     setData(Array.from(res))
   })
},[])
// creating async function
React.useEffect(()=>{
  const getData = async ()=>{
    const fetchResults = await fetchValues();
    const listData = Array.from(fetchResults);
    setData(listData)
  }
  // dont forget to call it
  getData()
},[])
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried but I couldn't make it work so I went for the solution by Yakup Malikov instead.

Comment: Ah I forgot to add `result=listdata` in `fetchValues`